# How to combine several queries into a report

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a php and mysql project. I have a main table from which two other queries have been created. I want to include these queries in a report which pulls in everything from those two queries

**Query 1 code:**

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX='M' THEN 1 END)AS MALE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX ='F' THEN 1 END)AS FEMALE,
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
    `group`
FROM
`htsreg`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        0 as `start`, 0.167 as `end`,'<=2months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        0.168 as `start`, 1 as `end`, '3-12months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        1.001 as `start`, 2 as `end`, '13-24months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        2.001 as `start`, 4 as `end`, '25-59months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        5 as `start`, 9 as `end`, '5-9years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        10 as `start`, 14 as `end`, '10-14years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        15 as `start`, 19 as `end`, '15-19years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        20 as `start`, 24 as `end`, '20-24years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        25 as `start`, 29 as `end`, '25-29years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        30 as `start`, 34 as `end`, '30-34years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        35 as `start`, 39 as `end`, '35-39years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        40 as `start`, 44 as `end`, '40-44years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        45 as `start`, 49 as `end`, '45-49years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        50, 200, '50 years and above'
) `sub`
    ON AGE BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
WHERE (TESTTYPE ='F')
GROUP BY `group`;
```

**Result:**

```
MALE    FEMALE  TOTAL   GROUP
0   1   1   10-14years
2   0   2   15-19years
1   0   1   20-24years
0   1   1   25-29years
1   0   1   3-12months
1   0   1   30-34years
1   1   2   35-39years
3   0   3   50 years and above
0   1   1   <=2months
```

**Query 2 Code:**

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX='M' THEN 1 END) AS MALE,
COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX ='F' THEN 1 END) AS FEMALE,
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL,
    `group`
FROM
`htsreg`
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
       0 as `start`, 0.167 as `end`, '<=2months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        0.168 as `start`, 1 as `end`, '3-12months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        1.001 as `start`, 2 as `end`, '13-24months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        2.001 as `start`, 4 as `end`, '25-59months' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        5 as `start`, 9 as `end`, '5-9years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        10 as `start`, 14 as `end`, '10-14years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        15 as `start`, 19 as `end`, '15-19years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        20 as `start`, 24 as `end`, '20-24years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        25 as `start`, 29 as `end`, '25-29years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        30 as `start`, 34 as `end`, '30-34years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        35 as `start`, 39 as `end`, '35-39years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        40 as `start`, 44 as `end`, '40-44years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        45 as `start`, 49 as `end`, '45-49years' as `group`
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        50, 200, '50 years and above'
) `sub`
    ON AGE BETWEEN `start` AND `end`
WHERE (TESTTYPE ='F' AND FINALRESULT='P')
GROUP BY `group`;
```

Result:

```
MALE    FEMALE  TOTAL   GROUP
1   0   1   3-12months
1   0   1   30-34years
1   0   1   35-39years
```

What I want is report with output like this:

Query 1 result

```
MALE    FEMALE  TOTAL   GROUP
0   1   1   10-14years
2   0   2   15-19years
1   0   1   20-24years
0   1   1   25-29years
1   0   1   3-12months
1   0   1   30-34years
1   1   2   35-39years
3   0   3   50 years and above
0   1   1   <=2months
```

**Query 2 result:**
Result:

```
MALE    FEMALE  TOTAL   GROUP
1   0   1   3-12months
1   0   1   30-34years
1   0   1   35-39years
```

In simpler terms I just want to have these on a single report

Comment: Offtopic: As MySQL caches aggregated results in the optimizer/execution as constants.. Using `SELECT COUNT(*) AS TOTAL, COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX='M' THEN 1 END) AS MALE, (COUNT(*)  - COUNT(CASE WHEN SEX='M' THEN 1 END)) AS FEMALE`  should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

1. store the result set in an array .
2. or create an temp table by inserting both query result in it

[inserting in table](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/insert-into)

Comment: Misguiding website, when a website says SQL tutorial i assume  ANSI/ISO standard SQL and not  SQL Server (MSSQL) syntax/functions usage like `CHARINDEX`.. Also this question is tagged MySQL..